# Sass ruby module, how to modify a Css property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I parse a Css configuration with the sass ruby gem. The idea it first get a tree for the css and then try to modify some of the properties in order to get a new css configuration. Here is the code I have so far:

```
require "sass"

DEFAULT_CSS = %Q{* {
  -GerminalTerminal-foreground: "#aeafad";
}
GtkWindow {
  -GerminalTerminal-background: "#323232";
  -GerminalTerminal-black: "#000000";
  -GerminalTerminal-red: "#b9214f";
  -GerminalTerminal-green: "#A6E22E";
  -GerminalTerminal-yellow: "#ff9800";
  -GerminalTerminal-blue: "#3399ff";
  -GerminalTerminal-magenta: "#8e33ff";
  -GerminalTerminal-cyan: "#06a2dc";
  -GerminalWindow-shell: "/usr/bin/fish";
}
GtkWindow GtkNotebook{  -GerminalTerminal-white: "#B0B0B0";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightblack: "#5D5D5D";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightred: "#ff5c8d";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightgreen: "#CDEE69";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightyellow: "#ffff00";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightblue: "#9CD9F0";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightmagenta: "#FBB1F9";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightcyan: "#77DFD8";
  -GerminalTerminal-brightwhite: "#F7F7F7";
  -GerminalNotebook-show-tabs: false;
}
}

engine = Sass::Engine.new(DEFAULT_CSS, :syntax => :scss)

root_node = engine.to_tree

root_node.children.each do |node|
  node.each do |prop|
    if prop.class == Sass::Tree::PropNode
      if prop.name[0] == "-GerminalNotebook-show-tabs"
        puts prop.value.class
        puts Sass::Script::Tree::Literal.new(true).class
        prop.value =  Sass::Script::Tree::Literal.new(true).class
        puts prop.value.class
      end
    end
  end
end

puts root_node.render
```

This result in the following output:

```
Sass::Script::Tree::Literal
Sass::Script::Tree::Literal
Sass::Script::Tree::Literal
/home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/script/tree/literal.rb:45:in `_perform': undefined method `source_range=' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:395:in `visit_prop'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `map'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `block in visit_rule'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:429:in `visit_rule'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
    from /home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
    from sass_test.rb:63:in `<main>'
```

If I don't modify the value, I have no error. So my problem is clearly related on how to modify the value in the tree in order to have a new css configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Sass::Script::Tree::Literal.new` take as argument one of the subclasses of `Sass::Script::Value::Base` which are

- `Sass::Script::Value::Bool`
- `Sass::Script::Value::Color`
- `Sass::Script::Value::List`
- `Sass::Script::Value::Map`
- `Sass::Script::Value::Null`
- `Sass::Script::Value::Number`
- `Sass::Script::Value::String`

Which leads to the following code:

```
root_node.children.each do |node|
  node.each do |prop|
    if prop.class == Sass::Tree::PropNode
      if prop.name[0] == "-GerminalNotebook-show-tabs"
        new_val = Sass::Script::Value::Bool.new(true)
        prop.value = Sass::Script::Tree::Literal.new(new_val)
        # instead of prop.value =  Sass::Script::Tree::Literal.new(true).class
      end
    end
  end
end
```